# Merging asc files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-2.4

I am trying to merge 8 .asc files using merge option in QGIS 2.4 but when I do that it makes like contour of the file when I want to merge the files together.

.ASC Files:

[image: the files that i try to merge and outline]

Result after merging:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: It looks like your NoData value is *very* small, like float.min 2.2250738585072014e-308, which is dragging the histogram down.  When you merged you have an option of initializing (-init) and also setting NoData (-a_nodata), I suggest you use -init -9999 -a_nodata -9999 and your histogram should look more normal.

Comment: Are you using the command `gdal_merge.bat`? Have you tried the GRASS GIS 7 command `r.patch` from the `Processing Toolbox`? I had some issues with the first one and I ended with the last one usually